# Filter the posts by a specific author

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display only one author's post  say "abc_author" . 
i have use the validation using if clause but THE PROBLEM is that i get pagination below the post where page 1 is blank (as an other author post is skipped) , page 2 (as an other author post is skipped) is blank and soon i get my desired post on page 6 . commenting  the verbosa_pagination() hide the pagination navigation but the starting pages are blank and 
I am a new to WordPress , i have also tries different plugin but they facilitate me to filter it on pages not post (though i can change the home page to a particular page but  i want it on default blog post for few reasons )

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div id="content-masonry">
            <?php /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        if(get_the_author()=='abc_author')
            {
            get_template_part( 'content/content', get_post_format() );
            }
            endwhile; ?>
        </div> <!-- content-masonry --> 
        <?php  verbosa_pagination();

    else : 
        get_template_part( 'content/content', 'notfound' );
    endif;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please try this code before the while loop?

```
 <?php query_posts( array( 'author' => 'your author ID' ) ); ?>
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#usage

Comment: also here is a resolved question about this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123920/wp-query-get-posts-by-specific-author-ids-if-one-of-several-logged-in-authors